# Scroll Image continuously in HTML / Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have around 7-8 images of Clients which I would like to display inside a `<marquee>` tag.

The problem arises when the last image and the first image has a lot of gap.
I would like the images to be displayed in a continuous loop.

This is the `HTML` code I'm using.

```
<marquee> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo1.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo2.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo3.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo4.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo5.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo6.png" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="img/logo7.png" alt=""></a></li>
    </ul>
</marquee>
```

I tried searching the net but couldn't find a relevant answer.

This is a sample which I found on the net but the loop works only once in my case.
[Sample](http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/photobanner/index.html)

Comment: Try searching for 'slideshow javascript css'.  The marquee tag has been deprecated and if you need your page to validate under HTML5, you can't use the marquee tag.  The Sample is old.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anilkabobo/pen/cvdmF  see this , I think solves your problem.

Comment: @chinmayahd : The link which you have given is that of an Image Carousel.
I do not want an image carousel. 
The carousel has to be clicked manually to display the next image. I want the next image to be displayed automatically in a continuous loop.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

Here is one in HTML5.

Personally I would avoid using marquee.

HTML

```
<div id="captioned-gallery">
    <figure class="slider">

        <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/50" />
        <figcaption>1</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/50" />
        <figcaption>2</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/50" />
        <figcaption>3</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/50" />
        <figcaption>4</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <figure>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/900/50" />
        <figcaption>5</figcaption>
        </figure>

    </figure>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@keyframes slidy {
20% { left: 0%; }
25% { left: -100%; }
45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
}

body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { 
margin: auto;
width: 80%;
max-width: 900px;
border: solid 4px white;
overflow: hidden; }

div#slider figure { 
position: relative;
width: 500%;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
font-size: 0;
animation: 30s slidy infinite; }

div#captioned-gallery { width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }

figure { margin: 0; }

figure.slider {
position: relative; width: 500%;
font-size: 0; animation: 30s slidy infinite; }

figure.slider figure { 
width: 20%; height: auto;
display: inline-block;
position: inherit; }

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) { 
figure.slider figure figcaption { font-size: 1.2rem; }
}

figure.slider figure figcaption {
position: absolute; bottom: -3.5rem;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
color: #fff; width: 100%;
font-size: 2rem; padding: .6rem;
transition: .5s bottom; }

figure.slider figure:hover figcaption { bottom: 0; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5xrbmaxo/3/